# Hide Total Size and Free Space on Network Drives

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, file-server, directory

I would like to know if there is a way, preferably through Group Policy, that one can hide the total size listing and the free space listing on network drives.  We have an active directory environment that we map network drives to a MS Windows File Server.  We are afraid that users will become either unnecessarily concerned about the free space that is displayed or they will think that it is a free for all chewing up whatever space they want.  I do know about the use of quotas and how that will change the visual display, but we are not able to implement quotas within our organization due to various reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will solve all of your problems, but you can use [disk Quotas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786220%28WS.10%29.aspx).  That way you can at least set the amount of space they will see.  If you are worried about them chewing up all available space then this will cap them.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  We ended up placing disk quotas on the user home drive mappings.  However, we have not been able to find an elegant way to approach the general/larger shares.  Marking as accepted unless something better comes along.